# How to create PowePoint presentation in OpenXML format with Apache Poi and XSLF?

Tags: powerpoint, apache-poi

If I go to [Apache POI XSLF](http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/index.html) there should be samples for both OLE2 and OpenXML specs, but there are only the OLE2 based Horrible Slide Layout Format examples.

Could please anybody help me out with XML Slide Layout Format example ? The API is quite different.

It is not like with [spreadsheet](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html) where one just change the implementation of HSSFWorkbook to XSSFWorkbook.

How would this look like with XSLF implementation ? POI apparently can't create a document from scratch, so we need an existing empty dummy document, right ?

```
      //table data              
      String[][] data = {
          {"INPUT FILE", "NUMBER OF RECORDS"},
          {"Item File", "11,559"},
          {"Vendor File", "300"},
          {"Purchase History File", "10,000"},
          {"Total # of requisitions", "10,200,038"}
      };

      SlideShow ppt = new SlideShow();

      Slide slide = ppt.createSlide();
      //create a table of 5 rows and 2 columns
      Table table = new Table(5, 2);
      for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
              TableCell cell = table.getCell(i, j);
              cell.setText(data[i][j]);

              RichTextRun rt = cell.getTextRun().getRichTextRuns()[0];
              rt.setFontName("Arial");
              rt.setFontSize(10);

              cell.setVerticalAlignment(TextBox.AnchorMiddle);
              cell.setHorizontalAlignment(TextBox.AlignCenter);
          }
      }

      //set table borders
      Line border = table.createBorder();
      border.setLineColor(Color.black);
      border.setLineWidth(1.0);
      table.setAllBorders(border);

      //set width of the 1st column
      table.setColumnWidth(0, 300);
      //set width of the 2nd column
      table.setColumnWidth(1, 150);

      slide.addShape(table);
      table.moveTo(100, 100);

      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
      ppt.write(out);
      out.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not implemented yet, org.apache.poi version 3.8-beta3, when it will be implemented is very unknown to me.

**XMLSlideShow.java**

```
public MasterSheet createMasterSheet() throws IOException {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Not implemented yet!");
}
public Slide createSlide() throws IOException {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Not implemented yet!");
}
```